# IOS 5 - Tab Bar Controller with Table View Controller issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I'm working on my first iPhone app in IOS 5 using storyboards. The root controller is a TabBar Controller that segues to a Table View Controller (TBarController) embedded in Navigation Controllers.

There are Detail Disclosure buttons on each cell if the Table View controller.  There is very little code at issue involved in the Table View controller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

TBarAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarController *tabBarC = appDelegate.tabBarController;
```

Using the debugger, the issue is that tabBarC is 'nil' when I click on the Detail Disclosure. 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  This is my first post to SO— please forgive the newbie character of the post.

Comment: FYI - In two weeks (Feb 1st) Apple will require all apps to fully support iOS 7. There is little reason to mess with iOS 5 any more. Support iOS 7 and maybe iOS 6.

Comment: Do you have a tabBarController property in your app delegate? It's also not at all clear why you're trying to access the tab bar controller this way. It would be helpful if you would clarify your controller structure.

Comment: Solved: I was not setting _tabBarController: